# How do I change this line of code from R to MATLAB?

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to convert

```
sigma.sqs[1] <- sigma.0 ^ 2
```

From R to matlab.

I have looked at some R to MATLAB cheat sheets, what is the [1] doing and what is the 0 doing?

Comment: Looks like sigma.sqs is a vector and this is extracting the first element.  sigma.0 looks like a badly named variable probably meaning sigma not. Take this with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sigma.0` is just a variable name or vector name

`sigma.sqs[1]` is equivalent of `sigma.sqs(1,:)` in matlab, it takes the elements of first row if sigma.sqs is a matrix/dataframe. Or is equivalent to `sigma.sqs(1)` in matlab and takes first element if it is a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `sigma.sqs` is a vector and this is extracting the first element. `sigma.0` looks like a badly named variable probably meaning `sigma naught`. You can proceed with the necessary MATLAB conversion.

```
sigma.sqs<-c(1,5,3,4)
```

To extract the second element of `sigma.sqs` we would do this:

```
sigma.sqs[2]
 #[1] 5
```

Therefore, the `[1]` in the above code is extracting the first element of a vector.

`sigma.0` as already stated is a badly named variable probably implying `sigma.naught` that is the initial value of sigma.

```
sigma.0<-2
```

Squaring the initial value can be done as follows:

```
sigma.0^2
#[1] 4
```

Then replacing the first value of sigma.sqs with the square of the initial value of sigma is done as follows:

```
sigma.sqs[1]<-sigma.0^2
```